# Proving with non-structural recursion in Lean4

Tags: lean4

I've defined a function (`foldMem` below) that Lean compiles into a `brecOn` eliminator. I need to reason with it later on, so I'm trying to prove a couple of lemmas to do so, but I'm stuck trying to prove the recursion lemma (`foldMem.step`).

What's the right way to go about this? Is this even necessary? [The docs](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/induction_and_recursion.html) say:

> The equation compiler generates such theorems internally. They are not meant to be used directly by the user; rather, the `simp` tactic is configured to use them when necessary.

but `simp` does not work for me with `foldMem`

```hs
import Std.Data.AssocList
open Std (AssocList)

namespace Std.AssocList

inductive Mem : α → β → AssocList α β → Prop
  | head (k : α) (v : β) (tail : AssocList α β) : AssocList.Mem k v $ AssocList.cons k v tail
  | tail (k : α) (v : β) {k2 : α} {v2 : β} {tail : AssocList α β} (pf : AssocList.Mem k v tail) : AssocList.Mem k v $ AssocList.cons k2 v2 tail

def Folder (as : AssocList α β) (δ : Type) := δ → (a : α) → (b : β) → AssocList.Mem a b as → δ

def foldMem (as : AssocList α β) (f : Folder as δ) (init : δ) : δ :=
  let rec go : (xs : AssocList α β) → δ → ({a : α} → {b : β} → AssocList.Mem a b xs → AssocList.Mem a b as) → δ
  | AssocList.nil, acc, _ => acc
  | AssocList.cons a b tail, acc, pf => go tail (f acc a b (pf $ AssocList.Mem.head ..)) (λ mem => pf $ AssocList.Mem.tail _ _ mem)
  go as init id

def foldMem.init (f : @Folder α β nil δ) (init : δ) : foldMem nil f init = init :=
  by simp [foldMem, go]

def foldMem.step (as : AssocList α β) (k : α) (v : β) (f : Folder (cons k v as) δ) (init : δ) :
  (foldMem (cons k v as) f init) =
  (foldMem as (λ d a b mem => f d a b <| Mem.tail a b mem) (f init k v <| Mem.head k v as)) :=
  by sorry

end Std.AssocList
```

Comment: Tip: Try to make a complete MWE, including where all the imports are given.  There should be no errors except the ones you are asking about.  (See https://leanprover-community.github.io/mwe.html for examples.)

Comment: Thanks. Updated with imports + namespace -- the `sorry` should now be the only error in lean4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jason Rute's suggestions, I was able to solve the issue. The challenge I was running into was that `go` closed over `f` and `as`, and my `step` lemma was trying to to 'throw away' the outer values. By moving `go` into an auxiliary definition and rejiggering the recursion, I got rid of the closure and the proof did indeed go through with just `rfl`

```hs
import Std.Data.AssocList
open Std (AssocList)

namespace Std.AssocList

inductive Mem : α → β → AssocList α β → Prop
  | head (k : α) (v : β) (tail : AssocList α β) : AssocList.Mem k v $ AssocList.cons k v tail
  | tail (k : α) (v : β) {k2 : α} {v2 : β} {tail : AssocList α β} (pf : AssocList.Mem k v tail) : AssocList.Mem k v $ AssocList.cons k2 v2 tail

def Folder (as : AssocList α β) (δ : Type) := δ → (a : α) → (b : β) → AssocList.Mem a b as → δ

def foldMem.aux (xs: AssocList α β) (acc: δ) (g: δ → (a : α) → (b : β) → AssocList.Mem a b xs → δ): δ :=
  match xs with
  | AssocList.nil => acc
  | AssocList.cons a b tail => foldMem.aux tail (g acc a b <| AssocList.Mem.head ..)
                                           (λ acc' a' b' mem' => g acc' a' b' <| AssocList.Mem.tail _ _ mem')

def foldMem (as : AssocList α β) (f : Folder as δ) (init : δ) : δ :=
  foldMem.aux as init f

def foldMem.init (f : @Folder α β nil δ) (init : δ) : foldMem nil f init = init :=
  by rfl

def foldMem.step (as : AssocList α β) (headk : α) (headv : β) (f : Folder (cons headk headv as) δ) (init : δ) :
  (foldMem (cons headk headv as) f init) =
  (foldMem as (λ d a b mem => f d a b <| Mem.tail a b mem) (f init headk headv <| Mem.head headk headv as)) :=
  by rfl

end Std.AssocList
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete solution, but here is how I would think of this.  First, your example is a bit complicated (and doesn't compile).  I simplified it a bit by just using a `List`:

```
inductive Mem : α → List α → Prop
  | head (k : α) (tail : List α) : Mem k $ List.cons k tail
  | tail (k : α) {k2 : α} {tail : List α} (pf : Mem k tail) : Mem k $ List.cons k2 tail

def Folder (as : List α) (δ : Type) := δ → (a : α) → Mem a as → δ

def foldMem (as : List α) (f : Folder as δ) (init : δ) : δ :=
  let rec go : (xs : List α) → δ → ({a : α} → Mem a xs → Mem a as) → δ
  | List.nil, acc, _ => acc
  | List.cons a tail, acc, pf => go tail (f acc a (pf $ Mem.head ..)) (λ mem => pf $ Mem.tail _ mem)
  go as init id


def foldMem.init (f : @Folder α List.nil δ) (init : δ) : foldMem List.nil f init = init :=
  by simp [foldMem, foldMem.go]

def foldMem.step (as : List α) (k : α) (f : Folder (List.cons k as) δ) (init : δ) :
  (foldMem (List.cons k as) f init) =
  (foldMem as (λ d a mem => f d a <| Mem.tail a mem) (f init k <| Mem.head k as)) :=
  by sorry
```

The helper lemmas for `foldMem.go` don't get created right away.  But since I used `foldMem.go` in a proof above, now I can see four lemmas associated with `foldMem.go`:

```
#check foldMem.go.
  -- foldMem.go._eq_1
  -- foldMem.go._eq_2
  -- foldMem.go.proof_1
  -- foldMem.go.proof_2
```

The first two are what you are looking for, especially `_eq_2`.

```
#print foldMem.go._eq_2
-- private theorem foldMem.go._eq_2.{u_1} : ∀ {α : Type u_1} {δ : Type} (as : List α) (f : Folder as δ) (_fun_discr : δ)
--   (a : α) (tail : List α) (pf : ∀ {a_1 : α}, Mem a_1 (a :: tail) → Mem a_1 as),
--   foldMem.go as f (a :: tail) _fun_discr pf =
--     foldMem.go as f tail (f _fun_discr a (_ : Mem a as)) (_ : ∀ {a : α}, Mem a tail → Mem a as)
```

(See the note at the bottom of this answer about the `_`s.)  You should never call `go._eq_2` directly, but it is good to at least know what it says.  As for your lemma, let's look at it again after we apply `simp` to strip away the `foldMem`:

```
def foldMem.step (as : List α) (k : α) (f : Folder (List.cons k as) δ) (init : δ) :
  (foldMem (List.cons k as) f init) =
  (foldMem as (λ d a mem => f d a <| Mem.tail a mem) (f init k <| Mem.head k as)) :=
  by
    simp [foldMem]    
    -- α: Type ?u.2152
    -- δ: Type
    -- as: List α
    -- k: α
    -- f: Folder (k :: as) δ
    -- init: δ
    -- ⊢ go (k :: as) f (k :: as) init (_ : ∀ {a : α}, Mem a (k :: as) → Mem a (k :: as)) =
    --   go as (fun d a mem => f d a (_ : Mem a (k :: as))) as (f init k (_ : Mem k (k :: as)))
    --     (_ : ∀ {a : α}, Mem a as → Mem a as)
```

You can start to see subtle differences between your lemma and the automatic `go._eq_2`.  I didn't take the time to see if your lemma is correct, or if it can be easily modified into `go._eq_2`, but if your lemma is correct then it should be provable by induction, possibly with some additional helper lemmas to get you started.  You will have to massage the theorem to be of the right form to apply the automatic `go._eq_2` theorem.  Here is how to start the induction on your lemma:

```
def foldMem.step (as : List α) (k : α) (f : Folder (List.cons k as) δ) (init : δ) :
  (foldMem (List.cons k as) f init) =
  (foldMem as (λ d a mem => f d a <| Mem.tail a mem) (f init k <| Mem.head k as)) :=
  by
    induction as with
    | nil => rfl
    | cons head tail ih =>
    -- case cons
    -- α: Type ?u.1797
    -- δ: Type
    -- k: α
    -- init: δ
    -- head: α
    -- tail: List α
    -- ih: ∀ (f : Folder (k :: tail) δ),
    --   foldMem (k :: tail) f init =
    --     foldMem tail (fun d a mem => f d a (_ : Mem a (k :: tail))) (f init k (_ : Mem k (k :: tail)))
    -- f: Folder (k :: head :: tail) δ
    -- ⊢ foldMem (k :: head :: tail) f init =
    --   foldMem (head :: tail) (fun d a mem => f d a (_ : Mem a (k :: head :: tail)))
    --     (f init k (_ : Mem k (k :: head :: tail)))
```

If it was me, I would find the "step" theorem most closely matching the automatic `go` lemmas, and then use that to prove other useful theorems.  (Also, I might even just move `go` outside the definition to make it easier to work with directly, but of course your question is specifically how to work with it if it is inside the definition.)

---

Edit: In this particular example, proofs inside definitions are involved.  Sometimes the Lean pretty printer hides proofs as in, e.g. `(_ : Mem a (k :: tail)))` above.  To see the proof that `_` refers to, use `set_option pp.proofs true`.

Edit 2: I'm not actually sure induction is needed since your `step` function is already supposed to be the induction/recursion step, but I haven't thought it through.

Edit 3: The `foldMem.init` is actually just provable with `by rfl` and I wonder if the "correct" `foldMem.step` lemma would be as well.  In that case, you wouldn't need to mention the internal `go` auxiliary function at all.